# MongoDB request that returns x elements in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in javascript, but I'd appreciate answers in pure MongoDB or mongoose.

Say we have a schema in our DB that looks like this:

```
{
  attr1: String,
  attr2: Number,
  arr: [String]
}
```

An object of this schema could have hundreds of elements in the array, but I would like MongoDB to only return the 5 most recent (last) elements in the array.

More explicit example:

Object in DB:

```
{
  attr1: "test",
  attr2: 4,
  arr: [ "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7" ]
}
```

Object that I want returned by MongoDB:

```
{
  attr1: "test",
  attr2: 4,
  arr: [ "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) projection operator:

```
db.test.find({}, {arr: {$slice: -5}})
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ..., 
  "attr1" : "test", 
  "attr2" : 4, 
  "arr" : [ "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7" ]
}
```

Passing a negative value takes the last N elements from the array.

Comment: Wow, I was half expecting this to not be possible. Works exactly how I wanted it to! Thanks!